# Django multiple databases (sanity check)

Tags: python, django, database, router

Afternoon. I've read a good number of places about the topic, taking info from each as they don't all appear consistent, and believe I have this working. As this is a test setup, I don't want to get months down the line to find something's not working --- and it turns out to be down to this.

Appreciate those more experienced than myself looking this over, and please make any suggestions.

`settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'myproject',
    'USER': 'myprojectuser',
    'PASSWORD': 'abc123',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '',
},
'ta1_db': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'testapp1db',
    'USER': 'ta1',
    'PASSWORD': 'ta1',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '',
},
'ta2_db': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'testapp2db',
    'USER': 'ta2',
    'PASSWORD': 'ta2',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '',
},
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['spiderproject.routers.DBRouter',]
```

`routers.py` (in main `spiderproject` folder)

```
class DBRouter(object):

def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    """Send all read operations on 'app_label' app models to associated db"""
    if model._meta.app_label == 'testapp1':
        return 'ta1_db'
    if model._meta.app_label == 'testapp2':
        return 'ta2_db'
    return None

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    """Send all write operations on 'app_label' app models to associated db"""
    if model._meta.app_label == 'testapp1':
        return 'ta1_db'
    if model._meta.app_label == 'testapp2':
        return 'ta2_db'
    return None

def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    """Determine if relationship is allowed between two objects."""

    # Allow any relation between two models that are in the same app.
    if obj1._meta.app_label == 'testapp1' and obj2._meta.app_label == 'testapp1':
        return True
    if obj1._meta.app_label == 'testapp2' and obj2._meta.app_label == 'testapp2':
        return True
    # No opinion if neither object is in the Example app (defer to default or other routers).
    elif 'testapp1' not in [obj1._meta.app_label, obj2._meta.app_label] and 'testapp2' not in [obj1._meta.app_label, obj2._meta.app_label]:
        return None

    # Block relationship if one object is in the Example app and the other isn't.
        return False

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    """Ensure that the 'app_label' app's models get created on the right database."""
    if app_label == 'testapp1':
        return db == 'ta1_db'
    if app_label == 'testapp2':
        return db == 'ta2_db'
    elif db == 'default':
        # Ensure that all other apps don't get migrated on the example_db database.???
        return False

    # No opinion for all other scenarios
    return None
```

**(The elif in allow_migrate() I'm not sure is correct. Also the elif in allow_relation(). I adapted these from an example)**

I've registered the models for testapp1 and testapp2 in their own admin.py, and they appear on the admin page - at this moment adding/removing data is ok, and I check they're storing independently.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your use case? A common one is to store multiple copies of a single schema, e.g. to support multiple clients, each with their own isolated storage. If that is your goal you might consider something like [`django-tenants`](https://github.com/tomturner/django-tenants).

Comment: At the moment I host my own Django/gunicorn/nginx site, with a single project spawned from a need to host a Lightroom database (sqlite3, read only - I may document this) based app. My intention is to change the site, keeping a single project structure, and have separate apps for different things (adding the existing Lr). I know it would be possible to have multiple projects and use nginx to route them, but I want to use apps for each site (very low client count). There may be different db types, which I'm comfortable with, Postgres is being used as an example, just to get routing working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here would be my recommended router.  Explanation in comments below

```
class DBRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """Send all read operations on 'app_label' app models to associated db"""
        if model._meta.app_label == 'testapp1':
            return 'ta1_db'
        if model._meta.app_label == 'testapp2':
            return 'ta2_db'
        # return None
        
        # I recommend returning 'default' here since 
        # it is your default database
        return 'default'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """Send all write operations on 'app_label' app models to associated db"""
        if model._meta.app_label == 'testapp1':
            return 'ta1_db'
        if model._meta.app_label == 'testapp2':
            return 'ta2_db'
        # return None
        
        # I recommend returning 'default' here since 
        # it is your default database, this will allow
        # commonly used django apps to create their
        # models in the default database (like contenttypes 
        # and django auth
        return 'default'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """Determine if relationship is allowed between two objects."""

        # Allow any relation between two models that are in the same app.
        # I prefer to make this global by using the following syntax
        return obj1._meta.app_label == obj2._meta.app_label


    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        
        # I think this was your biggest misunderstanding
        # the db_for_write will pick the correct DB for the migration
        # allow_migrate will only let you say which apps/dbs you 
        # should not migrate.  I *strongly* recommend not taking
        # the belt and braces approach that you had here.        
        return True
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll snapshot the vm and give this a try in a mo. I must say before trying it, it looks far more logical.